# Ask multiple input to user in FormFlow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, botframework

I'm working on a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework in c#.

I'm using a FormFlow like that:

```
return new FormBuilder<UploadFile>()
    .OnCompletion(processOrder)
    .Field(new FieldReflector<UploadFile>(nameof(UploadFile.Str))
        .SetType(null)
        .SetDefine((state, field) =>
        {
            foreach (string str in listStr)
                field
                    .AddDescription(str, str)
                    .AddTerms(str, str);
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        })
        .SetNext((value, state) =>
        {
            // Save value
            return new NextStep();
        }
        ))
        .Build();
```

After that, I would like to ask multiple input to user like a dialog and save each answer. I have a list of property i want to ask, but i have no idea how to loop a prompt for exemple.

I found [something like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-waterfall?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cstab#import-package-to-bot.). But this doesn't work for me, so I post this question here hopping someone can help me.

Comment: Is your `listStr` dynamic and will be different every time?  or will the list always be the same?.  Can you explain your scenario so we can better understand what you are trying to accomplish?  There may be a better way of doing this, but I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: listStr is dynamic, so yes it will be different every time. In my scenario, i'm getting some informations from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client to feed my list lisStr and I want to complete this information like i asked before.

Comment: This will not work trying to create undefined fields in fields. You will have to try something else.

One thing that could work for you is defining all the fields possible in your form.   Then for the ones you do not need,  based on the information in list use default values for the current user.  [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#specify-initial-form-state-and-entities) describes how you can use state to do this. It is hard to tell if this is even a viable option with the info you have given.

Comment: Thank you @JasonSowers for your quick answer, I will try on this way and will ask later with more details if i can't resolve it .